# Query multiple rowkeys in ksqlDB via pull query?

Tags: ksqldb

I'm trying to generate a report which should basically contain the rows of a Windowed KSQL Table. I want to group by search requests and clicked products to receive a count for each pair.

In the end I want to output all entries for a given window of the following table via **pull query**:

```
CREATE TABLE REPORT AS 
SELECT QUERY_STRING, PRODUCT_ID, count(*) AS COUNTER
FROM  INPUT_STREAM
WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 7 DAYS, ADVANCE BY 1 DAYS)
GROUP BY QUERY_STRING, PRODUCT_ID;
```

To only receive logs for a specific window is no problem. But apparantely ksqlDB can only query one rowkey (in my case query+productId) at a time.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
SELECT QUERY_STRING, PRODUCT_ID, COUNTER 
FROM REPORT 
WHERE '2019-12-09T21:31:16' <= WINDOWSTART;
```

Is my goal even possible/valid? Considering that Confluent advertises pull queries as "like SQL" it should be, I guess. Or maybe this is still an open issue?

Answer (score 1):

The current version of ksqlDB, (v0.10), only supports a very limited subset of pull queries.  What you're after does not *currently* work.  However, it is being actively worked on and what you're asking *will* work in a future version.

Until then, the recommended approach, when ever the pull query functionality is insufficient for your needs, is to materialize the table in an external store/db of your choosing.

For example, you could materialize your `REPORT` table into any JDBC compliant db, e.g. postgres, using the JdbcSinkConnector, (either directly from ksqlDB or via a standalone Connect cluster).  You can then query the data in postgres as you need.

Docs on ksqlDB CREATE CONNECTOR: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/create-connector/

JdbcSinkConnector docs: https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html

This pattern is actually extremely powerful. ksqlDB will never be all flavours of database to all users, nor should it try.  It's predominately a streaming database. It exists in a rich ecosystem, which includes connectors to allow you to get your data into whatever weird and wonderful databases and datastores you need, allowing you to meet any query patterns you can think of.